# errors from script to extract data from log

Tags: shell, logging, extract

I keep getting the following errors running a new shell script. I'm trying to extract errors from the log file to catch them before they cause an issue.

: not found [No such file or directory]
: not found [No such file or directory]
LogErrors.sh: line 5: syntax error at line 14: `if' unmatched
: not found [No such file or directory]
: not found [No such file or directory]
LogErrors.sh: line 5: syntax error at line 14:`if' unmatched
: not found [No such file or directory]
: not found [No such file or directory]
LogErrors.sh: line 5: syntax error at line 14: `while' unmatched

```
Code:


#!/bin/ksh

TOM1=/ap/mvr/servers/tomcat1/logs/
TOM2=/ap/mvr/servers/tomcat2/logs/

find $TOM1 $TOM2 -type f -name "mvr-gateway.log" | while read file
do
LOGERRORS=$(grep -B2 -A3 'WARN|ERROR|CRIT' $file)
if[[! -z $LOGERRORS]]
then
    echo "Errors in $file: $LOGERRORS" >> LogErrors.txt
fi
done
```

Comment: Your formatting is... not great.  Is everything after "Code:" to be read as code?  If so, if you prefix it with four spaces when editing it on SO, it will show up as `code`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your syntax is not quite right for ksh and you are using egrep syntax for grep.

I believe this will produce what you need:

```
#!/bin/ksh
TOM1=/ap/mvr/servers/tomcat1/logs/
TOM2=/ap/mvr/servers/tomcat2/logs/

find $TOM1 $TOM2 -type f -name "mvr-gateway.log" |
while read file
do
    LOGERRORS=$(egrep -B2 -A3 'WARN|ERROR|CRIT' $file)
    if [[ ! -z $LOGERRORS ]]
    then
        echo "Errors in $file: $LOGERRORS" >> LogErrors.txt
    fi
done
```

In the meantime, you may want to read in each line from the output of the `egrep`  with another `while read linein` (with the output piped from `egrep`).

Comment: I'm kind of new at shell scripting. How would that look with your suggestion added?

Comment: Not a problem.  Just remember that spaces are significant.  there have to be spaces before and after the [[ and ]] and no spaces before and after = for assignments.

Comment: Works like a charm now. Thanks!